# Зачем на нужны join если есть where?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Учу sql заново, и у меня возник вопрос зачем вообще нужны джоины. Объеденить таблицы ведь можно с помощью фореина и праймари ключей в таблицах и where. Этот вопрос и раньше возникал и был решён, но опять возникли трудности с пониманием.

Чтобы лучше понять о чем я, есть видосик где объясняется подобный способ: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdz4MRlzOyE&ab_channel=CrackConcepts

Comment: Как объединить? Вы имеете в виду `FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2` ? Или какой-нибудь `WHERE EXISTS (...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще говоря, подобные вопросы не для stackoverflow.com.

Есть несколько типов JOIN:

- `INNER JOIN`
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN`
- `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`
- `FULL OUTER JOIN`
- `CROSS JOIN`
- так далее

Большинство из них невозможно выразить с помощью предложения `WHERE`.

Comment: *Большинство из них невозможно выразить с помощью предложения WHERE.* Это неверно - абсолютно любой запрос может быть переведён в картезианское произведение с условиями отбора. Другой вопрос что эти условия получатся изрядно навороченными.

Comment: @Akina интересно увидеть это для любого outer join-a

Comment: @RomanKonoval UNION WHERE NOT EXISTS, например.

Answer (score 0):

#### FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2

Это **CROSS JOIN**, который в принципе можно урезать с помощью **WHERE** до нужного состояния.
Но при этом, вы полагаетесь на возможности планировщика СУБД.
Если он способен понять, что ваш **WHERE** аналогичен **JOIN**, то вы получите результат аналогичный **JOIN**, иначе вы рискуете нарваться на загрузку декартова произведения(**CROSS JOIN**) строк таблиц в память с последующей фильтрацией. =)

Comment: Неужели есть хоть одна реализация, где фильтрация применяется уже ко всему результату?

Comment: Ну, не ко всему результату. Скорее к n*m индексов. Допустим есть 2 таблицы one-to-one, в каждой по несколько лямов строк. И тут может возникнуть разница между триллионами и миллионами сравнений. Не уверен за mysql, а в каком-нибудь firebird планировщик частенько жестит)

Comment: *FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 Это CROSS JOIN, который в принципе можно урезать с помощью WHERE до нужного состояния.* Не совсем. Есть маленькая тонкость - все JOIN имеют одинаковый приоритет, тогда как приоритет запятой ниже. `FROM a CROSS JOIN b JOIN с ON a.id=c.id` - корректно, а `FROM a, b JOIN с ON a.id=c.id` приведёт к ошибке `Unknown table 'a'`, ибо эта конструкция по сути `FROM a, (b JOIN с ON a.id=c.id)`.

Comment: @Akina, таки да, но разве мы не отказались от всех join? =)

Comment: Не, я просто к тому, что это не абсолютные синонимы, и замена CROSS JOIN на запятую может преподнести сюрпризы. А LATERAL в MySQL появился вот только-только...

Comment: Стало интересно, а корректно ли тогда `FROM a JOIN c ON c.id=a.id, b`?

Comment: Хм, [работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b5f0e/1) =) Честно говоря, никогда не пользовался этой запятой)